# Zoom FPC in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

we use Zoom Full Page Cache from ezapps for Magento. The code can be found here:

https://github.com/ezapps/Zoom-Magento-FPC

Although we see that development has been silent for a while we still enjoy this product. We only see now that working with a multistore that site A is loaded in site B. But it is supposed to support multistore.

Our question is: Has anyone come across this issue for a multisite and know how to fix it?

merci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom looks for:

self::$STORE = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'])

The problem is that the ezzoom.php is the first line of PHP code in index.php

What yoou need to do is place the IF ELSE code for store selection based on domain ABOVE the call to ezzoom.php in index php

then it works fine

Now the code is like

```
$call to ezzoom.php on first line

OTHER CODE HERE

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
case 'winkel1.nl':
Mage::run('winkel2', 'website');
break;
case 'winkel2.nl':
Mage::run('winkel2', 'website');
break;
default:
Mage::run();
break;
}
```

and this needs to be

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'winkel1.nl':
    Mage::run('winkel2', 'website');
    break;
    case 'winkel2.nl':
    Mage::run('winkel2', 'website');
    break;
    default:
    Mage::run();
    break;
    }

$call to ezzoom.php on first line

OTHER CODE HERE
```

Then the environment variable is known by ezzoom

Comment: Hi I'm having the same problem, can you edit your answer to include a code example?

Comment: Ah I see what your problem is now. We had already setup our server config to corectly set $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] before index.php is even run.  In apache you can do this with your virtualhosts file or htaccess file.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup#virtualhost_solution